# How to custom serialize a property?

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization

I'm serializing a json into my Class:

```
[Serializable]
public class Feed
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string id_str { get; set; }
    public User user  { get; set; }
    public DateTime created_at { get; set; }
}

JavaScriptSerializer jss= new JavaScriptSerializer();
Feed feed = jss.Deserialize<Feed>(json);
```

There is a field called `created_at`, but I don't want to store it directly as it come from json, but processing it first, such as:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(created_at, "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

How can I do it?

Comment: How do you do the serialization?

Comment: Check it out the updated question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from using [JavsScriptConverters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you could use a trick like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class Feed
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string id_str { get; set; }
    public User user  { get; set; }
    public string created_at 
    { 
        get { return CreatedAt.ToString(FORMAT); }
        set { CreatedAt = DateTime.ParseExact(value, "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); }
    }
    [NotSerialized]
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Seems I cannot use `NotSerialized`?

Comment: Does it not work or do you get a (compile) error? I havn't tested this code - it was more or less the pattern I wanted to show you. JTMon's link as a more generic way of solving this problem I would prefer in this case...

Comment: Compile error. Seems that that class does not exist?!?!

Comment: It should: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nonserializedattribute.aspx

Comment: hey, if you like @chrfin solution then use it with out the NotSerialized it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can always define your own version of the JavaScriptSerializer with custom code for the datetime serialization deserialization and use that instead of the standard one. Take a look here for a good example

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/608464/CustomplusDatesplusJavascriptplusSerializer

EDIT

I have modified the code from the link above.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

// Your Organization serializer. Override the key methods for the desired date format.
// This example formats the date as MM/dd/yyyy
public class YourOrg_JavaScriptSerializer : JavaScriptSerializer
{
    public string CurrentFormat { get; set; }
    public YourOrg_JavaScriptSerializer(string format)
        : base()
    {
        this.CurrentFormat = format;
        this.RegisterConverters(new JavaScriptConverter[] { new DateStringJSONConverter() });
    }
}
public class DateStringJSONConverter : JavaScriptConverter
{
    private List<Type> supportedTypes;

    public DateStringJSONConverter()
    {
        supportedTypes = new List<Type>(1);
        supportedTypes.Add(typeof(DateTime));
    }

    public override object Deserialize(IDictionary<string,Object>
    dictionary, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dictionary
        ["DateString"].ToString(), GetFormatString(serializer), null);
        return dt;
    }

    private string GetFormatString(JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        var formatString = "MM/dd/yyyy";
        var mySerializer = serializer as YourOrg_JavaScriptSerializer;
        if (mySerializer != null)
        {
            formatString = mySerializer.CurrentFormat;
        }
        return formatString;
    }

    public override IDictionary<string,Object> Serialize(object obj, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        var dt = Convert.ToDateTime(obj);

        var dicDateTime = new Dictionary<string,Object>(1)
                              {
                                  {"DateString", dt.ToString(GetFormatString(serializer))}
                              };

        return dicDateTime;
    }

    public override IEnumerable<Type> SupportedTypes
    {
        get { return this.supportedTypes; }
    }
}
```

To use it:

```
var mySerializer = new YourOrg_JavaScriptSerializer("FormatThatINeed");
mySerializer.Serialize(obj);
```

The code of course still needs handling of defaults and error handling but it should illustrate my idea. One may be able to also make the formats static in the YourOrg_JavaScriptSerializer class as IDictionary and have a Serialize method that takes a MyDateFormatEnum along with the object, it would set the currentFormat property at call time before calling Base.Serialise(obj). The Dictionary can be initialized at application start.

Comment: I need custom type for custom field "on the fly". You solution is good for one scenario! What id I want two different type of DateTime?

Comment: You can make the format string a property that you inject into the class at creation time and have as many formats as you want.

Comment: Can you write a complete example for my case?